# How to get unique message id for email message across mailboxes using Microsoft graph API?

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I need a unique email message id which should be same across multiple mailboxes, means it should be unique in sender and receiver mailboxes.

Previously, I solved this problem with [singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0). Which allows you to add unique property to message and it remains unique across mailboxes. But unfortunately, this solution is not working for the past couple of months.

Another solution is to use **internetMessageId** property of message which is unique across mailboxes. But this id gets generated after the message sent. But I need such a unique id before the message sent.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Just a note for future searchers:

Messages have an immutable ID property that remains the same "as long as the item is in the same mailbox." 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id

Support for Immutable IDs is in v1.17 of the Graph Community Library:https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-contrib/blob/master/docs/ROADMAP.md#immutable-ids-for-outlook

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option as every mailbox will generate it's own message id upon creation. Can you give me example with singleValueExtendedProperty you had, I would like to find out why this isn't working in your case anymore.

Edit:

I just checked and doing it with extended properties works just fine. I used graph managed api to perform that and wrote test which shows this works as expected and tested with several mailboxes. Refer to this code

https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/blob/e8e6cca97eaa7570cf5bc4a3b4a4baae3e53c8fe/src/Microsoft.Graph.ManagedAPI.FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests/MessageTestDefinition.cs#L390

Comment: Nice solution Ivan!

Is the extended property sent in the message payload, and visible from the recipient mailbox?

Comment: Yes, it is. Test case I wrote validates that. Extended properties are transmittable, unless created through PR_INTERNET_HEADERS.